# Mocked method not invoked

Tags: mockito

```
public class Employee { 

    public void getAddress(){
        Address add = new Address();
        String a = add.addAddress();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}


public class Address {

    public String addAddress(){
        return "Emp Address";
    }
}

public class MockitoTest {

    @Mock
    Address add;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testEmployee(){
        when(add.addAddress()).thenReturn("mocked address");
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.getAddress();

    }
}
```

In the above example, I want to mock addAddress() method in address class.When I run mockito,it is calling the real method addAddress() than the mocked one and printing "Emp Address",instead of "mocked address".I need "mocked address" as output.

Comment: You create a mock Address instance, but Employee never uses that mock instance. It creates its own, real, not mocked address.

Comment: Mockito cannot work with new objects created inside your method(`Address add = new Address();`). You need PowerMockito for this.

Comment: What I need to change in the above code,so that it will invoke mocked 
address method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is as mentioned by @pvpkiran in the question comment. If you want to have mocked behavior, you need to provide provision to pass the mocked `Address` object to `Employee`.

One way to do that is

```
public class Employee { 

    public void getAddress(Address add) {
        String a = add.addAddress();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}


public class MockitoTest {

    @Mock
    Address add;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testEmployee(){
        when(add.addAddress()).thenReturn("mocked address");
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.getAddress(add);

    }
}
```

Edited: With Powermock (tested with `org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.4`)

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

class Employee {

    public void getAddress() {
        Address add = new Address();
        String a = add.addAddress();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}


class Address {

    public String addAddress() {
        return "Emp Address";
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Employee.class)
public class MockitoTest {

    @Mock
    Address add;

    @Test
    public void testEmployee() throws Exception {
        when(add.addAddress()).thenReturn("mocked address");
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Address.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(add);
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.getAddress();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh for your suggestion. But in my scenario, address objects has to be created inside getAddress() method.As per @pvpkiran suggesstion,Can anyone tell how to use powerMockito to resolve my problem.

Comment: @user3747490 I have edited the answer with powermock. Not it prints `mocked address` as you were expecting.